# Facebook/Google signup on Firebase on Android application

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, google-authentication

First time developing an Android application. Im trying to get the user register in our Firebase when sign in with FaceBook and Google.

So far I have the login with email and password. 
Sign-in with Facebook and Google.

The question is: Do you have to register the user in firebase (when sign-in from google and facebook) to be able to create a profile for example with a picture?

This scope of the code is been implemented on a Fragment on our project:

onCreateView

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_credential))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        //
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

Outside of onCreateView

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("MainACtivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("Main", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("MainAcitivyt", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

I followed FireBase guides on Signup with google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

> After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is created and linked to the credentials—that is, the user name and password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed in with. This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project, and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project, regardless of how the user signs in.

This is copied after the guide, Im just trying to find any google account on firebase that I have signed-up with in my application.

EDIT:

Find out that my application have an error when signin up with google:

here the logcat:

```
2019-03-13 11:29:25.729 10997-10997/com.itcom202.weroom W/LoginFragment: Google sign in failed
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.itcom202.weroom.LoginFragment.onActivityResult(LoginFragment.java:194)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4367)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: You don't have to manually register the user with Firebase, it automatically stores that information and you can see it in the `Authentication` tab on Firebase console. Inside app you can access currently signed-in user from `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Things to consider when coding the Firebase Sign-In Auth**

Follow the process covered in their Github repo and you can look at a few working sample activities in the [Firebase Quick Start Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) repo.

You'll also need to enable Facebook and Google Sign-In in your Firebase Console. Another important point is to make sure you are using the freshest google-services.json file every time you make a change with your Firebase Console.

Finally, make sure you have the required debug and release SHA1 fingerprints setup with you Firebase project in the Firebase Console to connect with the Firebase service when your app goes on Play store.

**Accessing your Firebase Registered User Accounts**

1. Log Into You Firebase Console.
2. Go to your Firebase Project and select Authentication in the left-hand side menu.
3. It will show a Users Tab with usernames, ids and authentication details.

For more look into Firebase documentation [online](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

> Do you have to register the user in firebase (when sign-in from google
>   and facebook) to be able to create a profile for example with a
>   picture?

For Google Sing-In, the profile image from Google Account and some more metadata is available that can be used.

The Google Sign-In method and Facebook Sign-In method examples on Github Quickstart automatically add new users if they're signing for the first time into the Firebase project. You can try adding a new user and see it being added on your Firebase Authentication Users tab. Seen Below:[image]

You can also give users the ability to sign out and delete their sign in accounts, also covered in the documentation and Github samples.